# Correctly patching git hunks with index editing

Tags: git

Updated:

you can reproduce this problem with below commands:

```bash
mkdir test && cd test
git init
cat > sample <<EOD
:host {
    max-width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;

    .svg-game-controller {
        width: 100%;
EOD

git add -A
git commit -m 'first'

cat > sample <<EOD
@import '../svg-icon.scss';

:host {
    @include svg-icon-default-style(20%);

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;

    height: 100%;

    .svg-game-controller {
        width: 100%;
EOD


git diff # check changes

git add -p # patch about diff

(interactive mode) s
(interactive mode) n # skip first hunk

# then you can see editing window.
```

---

I faced a problem about git hunk editing.

It can be resolved with patching hard split, but I don't want that and hope to know about git purely.

Please anyone describes to me about hunk editing correctly.

Following my knowledge, On manual hunk editing window,

you can check hunk info like below:

`<sign><start line in edit window>,<changed line counts (signed line with sources)>`

and there are two part like this: `@@ <delete change info> <add lines change info> @@`

example:
`@@ -1,7 +3,12 @@` means delete change is started on first line in edit window and lines including source content is 7 (all lines except + signed liens).

Then here is my target file.

```
diff --git a/src/app/svg-icon/logo-svg/logo-svg.component.scss b/src/app/svg-icon/logo-svg/logo-svg.component.scss
index c0f0c72..9500e10 100644
--- a/src/app/svg-icon/logo-svg/logo-svg.component.scss
+++ b/src/app/svg-icon/logo-svg/logo-svg.component.scss
@@ -1,7 +1,14 @@
+@import '../svg-icon.scss';
+
 :host {
-    max-width: 20%;
-    text-align: center;
-    cursor: pointer;
+    @include svg-icon-default-style(20%);
+
+    display: flex;
+    flex-direction: column;
+    justify-content: space-evenly;
+    align-items: center;
+
+    height: 100%;

     .svg-game-controller {
         width: 100%;
```

First, I splited the hunk to two part.

then skip first and edit second part.

```
diff --git a/src/app/svg-icon/logo-svg/logo-svg.component.scss b/src/app/svg-icon/logo-svg/logo-svg.component.scss
index c0f0c72..9500e10 100644
--- a/src/app/svg-icon/logo-svg/logo-svg.component.scss
+++ b/src/app/svg-icon/logo-svg/logo-svg.component.scss
@@ -1,7 +1,14 @@
+@import '../svg-icon.scss';
+
 :host {
-    max-width: 20%;
-    text-align: center;
-    cursor: pointer;
+    @include svg-icon-default-style(20%);
+
+    display: flex;
+    flex-direction: column;
+    justify-content: space-evenly;
+    align-items: center;
+
+    height: 100%;
```

---

then I have removed 7 lines like below:

```
# Manual hunk edit mode -- see bottom for a quick guide.
@@ -1,7 +3,12 @@
 :host {
-    max-width: 20%;
-    text-align: center;
-    cursor: pointer;
+    @include svg-icon-default-style(20%);

     .svg-game-controller {
         width: 100%;
# ---
# To remove '-' lines, make them ' ' lines (context).
# To remove '+' lines, delete them.
# Lines starting with # will be removed.
#
# If the patch applies cleanly, the edited hunk will immediately be
# marked for staging.
# If it does not apply cleanly, you will be given an opportunity to
# edit again.  If all lines of the hunk are removed, then the edit is
# aborted and the hunk is left unchanged.
```

I edited to -1,7 +3,5 but got error.

```
(2/2) Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,K,g,/,e,?]? e
error: patch failed: src/app/svg-icon/logo-svg/logo-svg.component.scss:1
error: src/app/svg-icon/logo-svg/logo-svg.component.scss: patch does not apply
```

I cannot understand why git works like this

HOW CAN I SUCCESS THIS HUNK PATCH ?

Comment: You are not supposed to change the `@@` lines, only delete `+` lines you don't want or change `-` lines you want to keep to space-starting lines, but change nothing else in the file.

Comment: Try using another tool : `git gui` for example

Comment: Otherwise : the `3` in `+3,12` seems to indicate that two extra lines were added before `:host {`. Try adding those lines in your patch as unmodified lines

Comment: @LeGEC but, on + sign, they are started '1' (of -1,7). I think first, second intro messages are not included on line count. 
I resolved with gui tool, but I hope to know answer this question.

Comment: Perhaps OP can confirm whether they split the hunk before editing, or whether this was an unchanged original hunk?

Comment: Oh, and please don't use screenshots of text. You can usually just paste it.

Comment: @cyan-kinesin You didn't give us enough information to reproduce the problem on our own computers, so I had to comment based on experience. Sometimes, that won't help, like here, but sometimes it does.

Comment: @joanis oh, thanks. I wrote scripts for reproduce. Unable patching situation is implemented too.

Comment: @Useless Thank you for your feedback. I replaced all images with texts. u r right.

Comment: @Useless
And, that concatenated texts cannot be splitted to more small hunk. So We used to edit manually. and sometimes, auto matching is not working but in general, you can patch forcibly with editing hunk editing head info. but in this situation it is not working although head info line is manipulated correctly.

Comment: @cyan-kinesin : can you please specify your OS and git version ? now that you added repro steps, I can, like jthill answered, apply the changes you want (Linux, git 2.38.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated: It was git bug on previous version (can be reproduced with 2.30.1)

on 2.38.1 bug is fixed

---

This is more a comment than an answer I can't make a clean comment-buffer version so:

> First, I splited the hunk to two part.
>
> then skip first and edit second part.
>
> then I have removed 7 lines like below:
>
> ```
> [(deleting all additions below the `@include`)]
> ```

When I do this, it works. Delete the additions you don't want to commit yet, `:x`, it applies. The working edit buffer I end with:

```
# Manual hunk edit mode -- see bottom for a quick guide.
@@ -1,7 +3,12 @@
 :host {
-    max-width: 20%;
-    text-align: center;
-    cursor: pointer;
+    @include svg-icon-default-style(20%);
 
     .svg-game-controller {
         width: 100%;
# ---
# To remove '-' lines, make them ' ' lines (context).
# To remove '+' lines, delete them.
# Lines starting with # will be removed.
# If the patch applies cleanly, the edited hunk will immediately be marked for staging.
# If it does not apply cleanly, you will be given an opportunity to
# edit again.  If all lines of the hunk are removed, then the edit is
# aborted and the hunk is left unchanged.
```

Comment: hmm something is strage. I can check it throws errors. 
you must go next step until saving then got error. you can check saving is failed.

Comment: No, I did save and exit, the patch applies. Maybe your editors set up to do strange things? Are you perhaps using an editor that saves in UTF16 by default?

Comment: I used Mac OS Monterey and iterm2 vi editor. I can check error on middle of my repository history or my reproduce script repo both. 
hmm.. what is your git version? my version is `git version 2.30.1 (Apple Git-130)`

Comment: And I don't think it is character format problem. Other situation hunk editing / patch is successful with head line modifications. Only that sole patching is failed one of all thats

Comment: Right. Just built 2.30.1, it fails. This is a bug, since fixed.

Comment: Wow you are right !! THANK YOU SO MUCH ! I realized important of updates. I'm so happy git is working successfully !

Comment: fwiw: there is a mention of a fix in [v 2.36.0](https://github.com/git/git/blob/319605f8f00e402f3ea758a02c63534ff800a711/Documentation/RelNotes/2.36.0.txt#L220), the release notes alone do not describe in what version the bug was introduced though.